# How to auto increment in Arduino Mega Board while loop?

Tags: while-loop, arduino, infinite-loop

Please understand that the tone is awkward using a translator

I coded the below code for Arduino Mega Board.

However, the value of buf_i is not increasing in the second while loop.

```
char buf[] = {0, };

if (Serial3.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial3.read();
    int nextChar = 0;
    if (inByte == 90) { //find Header 1
        nextChar = Serial3.read();
        if (nextChar == 165) { // find Header 2

            int buf_i = 0;
            int dataLen = Serial3.read(); // get Message Length

            //save data [ char buf[] ]  ---> works well!
            while (buf_i < dataLen) {
                buf[buf_i] = Serial3.read();
                buf_i++;
            }

            buf_i = 0;
            //print data to Serial ---> not work (Does not increase buf_i) 
            while (buf_i < dataLen) {
                Serial.print(" ");
                Serial.println(buf[buf_i]);
                buf_i++;
            }
        }
    }
    Serial.write(inByte);
}
```

and this is Serial Moniter Log

1. in Serial3 Message
   5A A5 06 83 21 00 01 00 11
2. in Serial Message
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMRlL.png)

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer you created has only one element.  If you try to insert more than one, then the behavior is undefined.

```
char buf[] = {0, };
```

You must make this buffer large enough for the largest message.

```
char buf[maximum_data_length] = {0};
```

Comment: Thank you so much i solved problem use this answer :)